# 400 Bad Request Request Header Or Cookie Too Large nginx

Tags: cakephp, nginx, cookies, bad-request

How should i solve this error on Real NGINX Server? When i was developing on local there was no error show with that. And it's only happen on Mobile and Tablet. Not happened on PC Browser. I searched in google and stackoverflow too but the problem solving is only one way. I've to give my project manager to different solving methods at least 2 - 3 methods. Because Server providers won't allow to config the NGINX config file so we can't use this method. Currently I found below method. Is there any other method to solve this error like adding some codes or something that we can use without server providers?

```
server {
   # ...
   large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;
   # ...
}
```

Developing Platforms : NGINX, Cakephp 3.x

Comment: Oops sorry for my bad. I already tried that method too but it's not working. Still showing error. Thanks you very much for helping me out.. Please continue to help me if you have not difficult time. Tarun Lalwani.

Comment: Then as discussed in that article, put a socat debugging and see what is is being returned by your app which is causing this issue

Comment: In my case (Cloud Foundry / NGiNX buildpack) the reason was the directive `proxy_set_header Host ...`, after removing this line nginx became stable