# How can I make nginx return 431 instead of 400 for Request Header Or Cookie Too Large?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I've got a default nginx config (I don't explicitly return `400` for any scenario):

```
http {
    ...
    
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    ...

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

and it returns

```
<html>
<head><title>400 Request Header Or Cookie Too Large</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>Request Header Or Cookie Too Large</center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
* Closing connection 0
```

which is OK.

However I'd like to alter nginx config to return `431` instead of `400` for that kind of error, what's the easiest way to do it?

I tried looking at the following questions:

- [nginx 431 Request Header Fields Too Large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56796481/nginx-431-request-header-fields-too-large)
- [400 Bad Request Request Header Or Cookie Too Large nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47130025/400-bad-request-request-header-or-cookie-too-large-nginx)
- [nginx 431 Request Header Fields Too Large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56796481/nginx-431-request-header-fields-too-large)

but they're more about fixing the error instead of returning a different status code.

The alternative solution could be to bump the limit:

```
server {
    # ...
    large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;
    # ...
}
```

by following https://stackoverflow.com/a/19285146/17109505.

I also found a [config](https://github.com/opendata-mvcr/react-nginx/blob/ab778707ac097f63000f0970d408a3506792b430/nginx.conf#L12-L27) that do `map $status $status_text {` under `http` block:

```
map $status $status_text {
...
        431 'Request Header Fields Too Large';
...
    }
```

will it be able to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't show anything from your real server config except the `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` so I can only guess what is it really contains. You can try to use [`error_page`](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) directive the following way:

```
error_page 400 =431 /431.html;
```

Create and put somewhere (for example, to the `/usr/share/nginx/html` folder) the following HTML file (again, you can put anything inside that file, this is just an example):

```html
<html>
<head><title>431 Request Header Or Cookie Too Large</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>431 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>Request Header Or Cookie Too Large</center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

This custom error page should't have any external assets (i.e. scripts, styles, images etc.) references (however you are ok to use any inline styles, scripts, or even BASE64-encoded images).

Now use the following location at your server block:

```
location = /431.html {
    internal;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
```

> I also found a [config](https://github.com/opendata-mvcr/react-nginx/blob/ab778707ac097f63000f0970d408a3506792b430/nginx.conf#L12-L27) that do `map $status $status_text { ... }` under `http` block:
>
> ```
> map $status $status_text {
>     ...
>     431 'Request Header Fields Too Large';
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> will it be able to fix that?

What an interesting solution! It uses an internal nginx variable [`$status`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_status) to get the error message from the response status code and then use those `$status` and `$status_text` variables via [Server Side Includes](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html) in the universal [`error.html`](https://github.com/opendata-mvcr/react-nginx/blob/main/error.html) error page. I see such a technique the first time, very nice approach. However I'm not sure it will be usefull for your particular case. If you'd want to use a similar universal error page, you will need at least two `error_page` directives:

```
error_page 400 =431 /error.html;        # change response status code from 400 to 431
error_page 401 402 403 ... /error.html; # left other response status codes unchanged
```